# Netbeans, can't save file

Tags: linux, netbeans, process, save, wait

I have a problem with netbeans, and i can't find a solution on google.

When i try to save a file, the pointer shows loading icon, and linux wait's indefinitely.

At this moment i can't even close netbeans, and have to run kill or pkill command.

Restarting netbeans or computer doesn't change that.
If i want to be able to save a file again, I have to kill netbeans, and remove the cache
(rm -rf ~/.cache/netbeans/8.0.2/*)

If I run strace -p , it gives me :
wait4(-1,

after removing cache and restarting netbeans, i can save file only if I don't change too much lines (about 10 lines are enough to crash netbeans again)

i have no idea about what is happening, i never had this problem before.
I think it could be a svn problem, or a disk size problem but I am absolutely not sure of that

This computer is my work computer, so i prefer not reinstall netbeans if you can help me to find out what's happening.

I am working on linux (centos 7) with netbeans 8.0.2

ps : this problem is on 1 file only, i can work fine with the rest of my project's files (of course that's the file I need right now :( )

ps2 :
I found some more details.
fuser ~/.netbeans/8.0.2/lock gave me a pid of a netbeans child process (his ppid is netbeans pid).
strace -p  gives me :
futex(0xa280a0c, FUTEX_WAIT, , NULL
So it seems a thread can't release futex?
Does that seems possible to you?
If yes how can I find if it's a netbean's bug or a system problem?

Comment: Check the permissions of the problem file.

Comment: The permissions are correct.I can edit this file with vim, gedit or others editors. Netbeans is the only one who has problems with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few days looking for a solution, i may have found what's happening.

It seems the problem doesn't come from netbeans but from centOS.
Apparently, CentOS 6.6 and 7.X have an error in the futex management (a default is missing in a switch).

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/QbmpZxp6C64

I don't know if the person who posted this is good in system administration, but after i found this post, i have found some more saying the same thing.

I don't use the solved button right know because i'm waiting for the administrator to look at this, but I post what I found if it can help someone else.